# Lagrange multiplier or not?

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

I have a hard time with Lagrange multiplier:

$$F(x,y)=x^2y$$

Constraint: $x+y=1$

Are there a max and min on these constraint?

Ackording to my calculations:

$$L(x,y,\lambda)= x^2y - \lambda(x+y-1)$$

I get:

$x=0$, $y= 0$ or $x=2/3$, $y=1/3$

According the solution: NO, there are no max/min.

Why does not the Lagrange Multiplier react to this? I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Minor comment, it is $x=0,y=1$. The Method identifies a list of candidates for maximumhood/minimumhood. **If there is** a max (resp. min) then it will occur at one of these places.

Answer (score 2):

You can just plug in $y=1-x$ to the function to get $f(x,y)=x^2(1-x)=x^2-x^3$ along the curve. So the extremum occurs when $$\frac{d}{dx}(x^2-x^3)=2x-3x^2=x(2-3x)=0\implies x=0,2/3$$ as you said. The second derivative is $$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(x^2-x^3)=2-6x$$ which is $2$ at $x=0$ and $-2$ at $x=2/3$. Therefore $x=0$ gives a *local* minimum and $x=2/3$ gives a *local* maximum.

However, there are no *global* extrema because the function's range is all of $\mathbb{R}$. It is an odd polynomial.

Comment: Ah, ok. The question was if the f(x,y) has a max/min ON the constraint. Thanks  "+1"